# Is Android Volley Dead?

Tags: android, android-volley

I presently use volley for network calls.
But, Google doesn't seem to be actively maintaining volley.
I heard that google initially developed volley to use it for its play store app but they haven't mentioned it in their list of 3rd party libraries used.
Almost everyone uses Retrofit(looking at the benchmarks, Retrofit seems better option), is it time to quit using volley?

p.s: please don't post the pros and cons of volley and retrofit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Google doesn't seem to be actively maintaining volley

That depends entirely on how you define "actively maintaining". Development is ongoing, as you can see by looking at [the Volley git repo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/), which shows many commits over the past year (as of the time of this writing).

Google also shipped [an official Volley artifact](https://bintray.com/android/android-utils/com.android.volley.volley/1.0.0/view) earlier this year, as version 1.0.0.

> but they haven't mentioned it in their list of 3rd party libraries used

Google wrote the Play Store app. Google wrote Volley. Hence, from *Google's* standpoint, Volley is not a third-party library. For anyone *other than Google*, Volley is a third-party library.

> Almost everyone uses Retrofit

Retrofit is not equivalent to Volley. The triad of Square HTTP libraries (OkHttp3, Retrofit, Picasso) would be equivalent to Volley, and that combination exceeds Volley's capabilities.

Based on questions here at Stack Overflow, I do not believe that "almost everyone uses Retrofit".

> is it time to quit using volley?

Nobody can answer that other than you. You are the one with decision criteria of importance to you. You are the one who needs to evaluate which libraries meet those criteria.

Comment: @SarthakMittal: "as we can see that the last commit was 3 months ago" -- I would not expect there to be lots of changes going forward. Volley is driven by Google's needs. So, their focus will be on improving compatibility and adding limited features that they happen to need. That does not mean that Volley is "dead", any more than a steel girder is "dead" once it comes out of the steel plant. If you are looking specifically for projects that have a more obvious track record of accepting outside contributions and feature improvements, the Square libraries will be more to your liking.

Comment: thanks for answering my questions :)